# How do I open a new Window in WinUI3 with WinRT/C++?

Tags: windows-runtime, winui-3, cppwinrt

How do I open a new window in WinRT / WinUI3? I want to click a button and open up another floating window on top of the current / main window.

I have tried code from several samples with zero luck:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/windowing/windowing-overview

  - I can't import <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Windowing.h> (the dll does not load)
- https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/AppWindow/cppwinrt/Scenario3_Size.h

  - This uses the old Windows:: namespace (not appropriate)
- https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-3-Demos/tree/master/src/ContosoAirlinePOS

  - Does not navigate to a new window (BoardingPassWindow is actually a Page, not a Window)
- `Frame.Navigate(xaml_typename<NewWindowClass>())`

  - does not work / exception thrown
- ```
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame rootFrame{ nullptr };
    auto content = Window::Current().Content();
    if (content)
    {
        rootFrame = content.try_as<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame>();
    }
  ```
- above snippet^

  - `Window::Current().Content();` throws an exception when called
- `appWindow = Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window(this, {}); appWindow.Activate()`

  - throws exception

The majority of the C++ WinUI3 documentation still only has C# code samples in it and is largely useless to me for that reason. I just want to open a new window and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Windows App SDK Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples) and for example modify this method:   [void DemoPage::TitleBtn_Click](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/main/Samples/Windowing/cpp-winui/SampleApp/DemoPage.xaml.cpp#L27)

like this:

```
void DemoPage::TitleBtn_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    auto window = Window();
    auto tb = TextBlock();
    tb.Text(L"Hello");
    window.Content(tb);
    window.Activate();
}
```

Which looks exactly like the C# sample here: [Create a new Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=winui-3.0#create-a-new-window)

```
var window = new Window();
window.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "Hello" };
window.Activate();
```

Comment: In project reunion 0.8.2 I'm getting an exception at `CreateInstance(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& baseInterface, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable& innerInterface)` with this code. I tried it with a 1.0.0 experimental project and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm using the "standard" Project Reunion 0.8.3.52036702 from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#version-08. Make sure you C++/WinRT is also up to date (I'm using 2.0.210913.7). What exception do you have? on which CreateInstance?

Comment: `auto window = Window();` gives me an Unhandled Exception 0xC000027B. I confirmed all my nuget packages are updated to latest.

Comment: C++/WinRT and Project Reunion are not nugets: https://i.imgur.com/kvfyaDC.png

Comment: C++/WinRT comes in two parts: The VSIX (responsible for project creation), and the C++/WinRT [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/) containing the code generator and base library. The latter is a required build dependency, while the former is (technically) optional.

Comment: true, I just remember having weird problems some times ago when the vsix was not up to date. Now I always check all this blindly...

Comment: The split was part of the transition from C++/WinRT v1 to v2. The C++/WinRT v1 code generator and base library shipped as part of the Windows SDK. Deploying the generator and library via the NuGet platform decoupled C++/WinRT from the Windows SDK, allowing it to progress at its own pace. With v2, having the VSIX up-to-date isn't quite as important as in the v1 timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade to Project Reunion 1.0.0 EXPERIMENTAL or higher to use `<winrt/Microsoft.UI.Windowing.h>`. You can then create an `AppWindow` as follows:

```
auto appwind = winrt::Microsoft::UI::Windowing::AppWindow::Create();
appwind.Title(L"New Window Title");
appwind.Show();
```

This does NOT work in project reunion 0.8.2 or 0.8.3 stable releases.